# How do i populate a ListView using x:Bind and System.Collections.Generic.List and generate columns

Tags: c#, listview, gridview, win-universal-app, xbind

I am trying to populate a [ListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nb-no/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listview.aspx) with a [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) while setting the ItemsSource as a `x:Bind`, and i cant figure out how to make columns and make the items display properly.

Here is what i got so far:

**The Customer class in Database.cs**

```
public class Customer
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Adress { get; set; }
    public int PostCode { get; set; }
    public string PostArea { get; set; }
    public string CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

**The FetchCustomer method in Database.cs that returns a list of Customer objects**

```
public List<Customer> FetchCustomer()
{
    using (SQLiteConnection _connection = new SQLiteConnection(sqlitePlatform, dbFilePath))
    {
        List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
        var _customers = _connection.Table<Customer>();
        foreach (Customer customer in _customers)
        {
            customers.Add(customer);
        }
        return customers;
    }
}
```

**The CustomerView Page**

```
public sealed partial class CustomerView : Page
{
    public List<Customer> CustomersFromDB { get; set; }

    public CustomerView()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        ReadyCustomers();
    }

    private void ReadyCustomers()
    {
        var db = new Database();
        CustomersFromDB = db.FetchCustomer();
    }
}
```

**The XAML where i bind the ItemsSource**

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{x:Bind CustomersFromDB}"/>
```

How do i go forward making this so that columns are auto generated and the items display properly?

I have tried to add [ListViewHeaderItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewheaderitem)s and browse through the differerent properties but havent found out how yet.

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{x:Bind CustomersFromDB}">
    <ListView.Header>
        <ListViewHeaderItem ???></ListViewHeaderItem>
    </ListView.Header>
</ListView>
```

The result i get with nothing else than the binding is this:

[image: Snapshot of the app illustrating that the ItemsSource is working but not as intended as it only shows: AuraFaktura.Customer in each ListViewItem]

## Update


I have made some progress today and i now have correct data output. I found out that with the use DataTemplate's i can set Binding on elements.

I still struggle with showing the data in correct manner.

Here is the XAML i now have written:

```
<GridView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{x:Bind CustomersFromDB}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <GridViewHeaderItem Content="CompanyName"></GridViewHeaderItem>
    <GridViewHeaderItem Content="FirstName"></GridViewHeaderItem>
    <GridViewHeaderItem Content="LastName"></GridViewHeaderItem>
    <GridViewHeaderItem Content="Phone"></GridViewHeaderItem>
    <GridViewHeaderItem Content="Email"></GridViewHeaderItem>
    <GridViewHeaderItem Content="Adress"></GridViewHeaderItem>
    <GridViewHeaderItem Content="PostCode"></GridViewHeaderItem>
    <GridViewHeaderItem Content="PostArea"></GridViewHeaderItem>
    <GridViewHeaderItem Content="Comment"></GridViewHeaderItem>
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <GridViewItem BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                <GridViewItem.Content>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CompanyName}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Phone}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Email}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Adress}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PostCode}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PostArea}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Comment}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CreatedDate}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding UpdatedDate}"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </GridViewItem.Content>
            </GridViewItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

And the result:

[image: Snapshot of the app illustrating that the DataTemplate is somehow working but not displaying as intended as the items are truncated and the header items are not showing.]

So as you can se the GridViewHeaderItem's are not showing and the GridViewItem's are not showing properly.

Here is the result i want to end up with:

[image: Snapshot of the result i want to end up with]

How would i go forward writing my XAML to achieve such a result?

Answer (score 0):

Just apply margin to the textblocks  margin="5,0,5,0"